# The underlying curve of a family of genus zero $n$ punctured curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X$ be a curve of genus zero over an algebraically closed field $k$ so that $X \cong \mathbb{P}_k^1$. Let $(C, s_1, \cdots, s_n)$ a $n$ punctured genus zero curve over $k$ where $s_i: k \to C$ are sections. Sine $C$ is a genus zero over $k$, we have that $C \cong \mathbb{P}_k^1$.

Now let $B$ be an affine scheme over $k$ and suppose consider the family of $n$-punctured genus zero curves $(C \to B, s_1, \cdots, s_n)$ where $s_i:B \to C$. Let us always assume that $n \ge 4$.

At this point, I tend to come across statements inferring that since the fibers of the family $(C \to B, s_i)$ have non non-trivial automorphism $C \cong \mathbb{P}_B^1$. Here I by no means am claiming that the family $(C \to B, s_i)$ of $n$-punctured curves is trivial but rather that the (total space) of the family of genus zero curves over $B$  "underlying" the family $(C \to B, s_i)$ is trivial.

Why does the automorphism group of the fibers of a family $(C \to B, s_i)$ being trivial imply that the underlying family of genus zero curves over $B$ is trivial? Again I mean this in the sense that the total space $C \cong \mathbb{P}_B^1$.

Comment: $n\geq 3$ is enough: for each $b\in B$, there is a unique isomorphism $u_b:\mathbb{P}^1\rightarrow C_{b}$ mapping $0,1,\infty$ to $s_1(b),s_2(b),s_3(b)$. 
Just map $B\times \mathbb{P}^1$ to $C$ by $(b,z)\mapsto u_b(z)$.